# How can I check if a button is pressed from another class?

Tags: java, class, jbutton, actionlistener

In my code, on one class, I'm trying to check if the button has been pressed on my other frame (class). If this is true, then some code will be carried out. However, I cannot find any code whatsoever to check if the button has been pressed or not.

Here is my code:

```
editBanana bFrame = new editBanana();

String getLocation = bFrame.editLocationField.getText();
javax.swing.JButton saveButt = bFrame.saveEditButton;

...
...

//If button is pressed from my other form, then do this code
if (saveButt.getModel().isPressed())
{
   System.out.println("Saved");
}
```

When I run this code, and press the button, this code does not work and nothing happens.

I'm thinking because this isn't working, that it runs through this code first, and then I press the button. So for the code where I click my button, I simply call the main class again so that it iterates through the code with the button now pressed. But it still does not execute my code.

Which code should I be using in order to find whether or not my button has been pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: should use an actionlistener to do this. the query `saveButt.getModel().isPressed()` is not executed on the press of the button. instead, the button's actionlistener is called. create an actionlistener for that button which then can be called

Comment: Ah yes, I'd thought so. But I'm having trouble implementing it between two different classes. Guess I had better do more research, I'm only new to java.

Comment: while it might not be entirely OOP kosher, you could try adding an actionlistener to `saveButt` in this class. Though, a note about java code conventions, classes are capitalised, so `editBanana` ought be refactored to `EditBanana`.